# bootstrap standard navbar search form splits on chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn bootstrap but however i'm facing problem with multi-browser support. standard inverse navbar looks fine on firefox but search form splits on chrome. I tried using col-sm-* but was no help? Why i'm facing this issue?Is there anyway to solve this problem without custom css?? I checked this question too [Bootstrap navbar-form width issue on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805443/bootstrap-navbar-form-width-issue-on-chrome)
This is somewhat similar issue but in my case search icon goes to rightmost corner of nav and input field on leftmost corner. Here is my html for navbar[image: This is how it appears on chrome][image: This is firefox view and it looks fine]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="padding-right: 10px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class=" nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
        </li>
      </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>
                  </span>
            </div>
       </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML

Comment: I've included my html and images for both firefox and chrome

Comment: I get this all the time. There isn't a lot of information out there, but I notice that even when I follow the examples word for word, my own pages have the same split problem. Have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to:

- remove the class, "navbar-left", from the form tag on line 18,
- and the class, "form-group", from the div on line 19.

So:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
```

Make it:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
<div>
```

Comment: Not working, after making these changes even firefox is rendering the same way as chrome.

Comment: It's fixed in that second example, Chrome and Firefox. Can anyone else verify this?

Comment: Okay i added col-md-1 on form class then it's working but when i try to add dropdown sign in form or any component on the right of navbar it falls down on second line. And to add with this if i use seperate search button instead of input group then everything works perfectly. All issues are being raise because of input group for search form and button

Comment: I think you're using some unnecessary helper classes that are making your elements block level. Systematically remove these one-by-one and zero in on your bug using logic and process of elimination.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this adding fixed width in the form-group div:

```
<div class="input-group" style="width: 150px;">
                        <input type="text" name="q" style="width:150px" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Recherche">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" formaction="index.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

See doc here (and look at the bold note): [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms)